# Add Item for OptionsButton is Gone from the editor

Tags: gui, godot, interface, hud, user-interface

When i added in a optionbutton for my hud i couldnt find a way to add items manually,this was weird as when i looked for a way,a button on top of the editor should appear but its not there?
I dont know why and it seems to be a problem all over my project,i am not sure if this happends in other projects as i havent checked.
Here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is currently (Godot 4) on the inspector.

Open "Items":

[image: Items]

And there you will find an "Add Element" button:

[image: Add Element]

Clicking it will create an empty item that you can then customize (add text, etc):

[image: New Item]